# Do you know any SQLite visual develoment tool?

Tags: sqlite

Do you know about any visual development tool such as Microsoft Access or FileMaker but that uses SQlite as database engine?

I'm looking for a Windows desktop software (or easy programming language) with which I can build a database application that uses SQLite.

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that MS Access is *not* just a "database browser/UI". I doubt there is anything like it, although there are plenty of "database browser/UI" applications that support SQLite. (I have no idea what FileMaker is.)

Comment: Yes you are right 'pst'. In fact I'm not looking for a SQLite manager I know there are plenty. I'm looking for a visual development tool for SQLite AS Access. FileMaker is the Apple side of 'Access'.

Comment: It's 2016. In my opinion, this has a better, more recent answer here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/sqlite-gui-editor

Answer (score 6):

I find [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) in first of google search result.

You can download it from here: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Some important features:

- Free
- Open source
- Many platform support (windows, mac, linux)
- Recently updated
- Simple
- Lightweight

[image: screenshot sqlitebrowser]

Answer (score 4):

At last I found [dBExForm](http://www.willmansoft.com). It's a GUI form editor for a number on SQL databases such as: Access, MsSql, MySql, Oracle, SQLite.

From the developer web site:

> Connect designer to database and get tables and fields direct from
> database. User or designer can drag and drop components fields and
> tables to the form. Simple edit form for single table will be ready in
> couple minutes. DBEXform helps to build small or large applications by
> creating forms, grids, reports, search, sorts and etc. features with
> couple clicks. More sophisticated solutions can be made with free hand
> designer powered with full programming capabilities in .NET Framework
> environment.

I tested it a little and it seems a good product. Unfortunately it is not cheap: 265USD.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl).

[image: Screenshot of the SQLite Studio client]

The project is maintained since 2007 (as of 2018). It's multiplatform, [*feature rich*](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) and can be extended by [plugins](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/Official_plugins).

Full history [is available](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/SQLiteStudio) if you feel like curious.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/), based on Eclipse.

It is described as a *free multi-platform database tool for developers, SQL programmers, database administrators and analysts*.

An *[Enterprise Edition version](https://dbeaver.com/) also supports non-JDBC datasources (WMI, MongoDB, Cassandra, Redis).*

A PPA for Ubuntu exists:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:serge-rider/dbeaver-ce
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dbeaver-ce
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [SQLite Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/)
2. [DataPro](http://www.vive.net/products/datapro.htm)
3. [SQLPro](http://www.vive.net/products/sqlpro.htm)

And [others](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools).

Comment: Thank you Microfed, as explained above I'm not looking for a SQLite manager. I'm looking for a visual development tool as Microsoft Access with drag&drop visual controls, GUI editor, etc.

Comment: I do not really understand what do you mean, but according to my knowledge, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access), Microsoft Access is a relational database management system. SQLite Maestro is an analogue for SQLite. If it ([Database Designer](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/maestro/screenshots/getting_started/database_designer/)) is not GUI, what is it?:)

Comment: @Microfed MS Access allows, among other things, custom forms and reports, macros, and embedded scripting ... pretty much everything to create an entire database-driven Application without ever leaving MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

So after a WHOLE lot of searching and trying things, I seem to be coming down to an old standard... Delphi.

Delphi + SQLite + a visual manager seem to make a good substitute to Access that is cross platform and doesn't require me to write VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything that will be as easy to use as FileMaker for creating a database front end. Therefore I have two suggestions.

1. Use FileMaker and forget about SQLite. If you're using SQLite, you are probably not building a shared database system, and FileMaker would probably work for this. Is there a specific reason you're deciding on SQLite for your database storage?
2. Use [Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com/realstudio/). It isn't as easy to build reports with Real Studio as with FileMaker, but it can create a front-end to a SQLite system.